# What are some important feeds to subscribe to for web developers?

Tags: language-agnostic

What are some of the feeds you subscribe too?

I already have a feed aggregate with 20+ feeds on it, but I find myself still feeling out of the loop and am looking for more on anything that relates to web development (back and front -end).

Comment: Any particular area of "web" development? UI code? Server code?

Comment: Both (back and front -end). I want to at least know about as many things as possible

Comment: Also, explanations for why this should be closed would be helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CodingHorror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/) is the obligatory first, with [JoelOnSoftware](http://joelonsoftware.com/) in close second followed by [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/).

Other greats include [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/), [24 ways](http://24ways.org/), [Ajaxian](http://ajaxian.com/) and [FiftyFourEleven](http://www.fiftyfoureleven.com/)